# How to Make Light indicate No-VPN connection Active?

Tags: cyanogenmod, vpn

I would like to put Red-light on if no VPN connection is active in my phone. I think the problem is not about choosing the best VPN application [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_vpn) to make VPN connection, but about to find an application which finds if VPN connection is active and affects the front-light of the phone.

Phone: Samsung Galaxy S4 gt-i9506
System: CyanogenMod 13, Temasek's unofficial ROM with patches
VPN client: NordVPN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Izzy's idea about using Tasker for the task in chat

> A raw idea (not checked/verified) would be using an automation tool like Tasker and have it shutdown all network interfaces whenever VPN connection "got lost" (of course giving you a "manual backdoor", i.e. if you manually enable networking it shouldn't shut it down immediately again just because no VPN is active ;)

Solution

1. Create VPN profile in Settings > More > VPN
2. Attach it to Tasker

Feature-request: enable the front light configuration in the VPN menu